# View full resolution on mobile device

Tags: css, html, resolution

Ive been on multiple website where onload where the website is zoomed out to keep resolution and therefore stopping overlaps on the mobile page.

Im not sure i am explaing my question correctly.  As i am a new member, i will add links to the differences.

I have tried some css3 media queries and some meta tags i have found online but nothing is working for me at the moment.

Here is the link to my site:
http://conorpendlebury.com/

As you can see from the image below there is overlapping with the navigation bar which pushes the content too far giving a squished appearance.
http://conorpendlebury.com/Images/Screenshot.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to make your `#Sidebar` to overlap your `#MainContent` and `#Footer` when activated while `#Bio` wont squish?

If so, make your `#MainContent` and `#Footer` with `position: relative` and `z-index: -1` and remove whatever is making their `marginLeft` equals to `document.getElementById('Sidebar').style.width` while activated.

If you intended to make it squished, you need a function to recalculate and reapply css to `#MainContent` and `#Footer`.

Comment: I actually like the transition on the desktop website.  It's the mobile phone that is the problem. I'm looking for a way that I can either zoom the mobile version out to portray it to be the desktop OR just overlap rather than squish on the mobile.

Comment: Squishing contents on small screen can become a user-experience problem because they probably cant read anything that is too small. Unless the mobile is in landscape orientation, the desktop layout won't work well on mobile version.

Comment: And is there a potential way of just changing for just mobile.  Media queries etc...

Answer (score 0):

To build a offcanvas navigation you set the page to translateX the size of the navigation. So the container keeps the width. 
Here is a [example](https://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu/).

It's possible to code this without JavaScript.